# php concatenation for url setup. How to do it?

Tags: javascript, php

This here is the php setup for

```
echo '<a href="javascript:delpost(' . $row['postID'] . ',' . $row['postTitle']. ')">Delete</a>';
```

which will display

```
javascript:delpost(5, article name)
```

How would I properly concatenate this to display

```
javascript:delpost("5, article name")
```

Can someone explain the way I would do this and what you need to add to make this possible?

Comment: Have you tried inserting `\"` in the string?

Comment: uh... add `"` into your echo statements? `...delpost("'......'")'...`?

Comment: tried that... it displays javascript:depost( and no more

Comment: Please include your attempt in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf):

```
echo sprintf('<a href="javascript:delpost(\'%d, %s\')">Delete</a>', 
    $row['postID'], $row['postTitle']);
```

This would output something like:

```
<a href="javascript:delpost('42, Some Title')">Delete</a>
```

Comment: You cannot use double quotes within a double quoted string. It should be `\"`.

Comment: @ComFreek: [Fixed.](https://eval.in/56550)